# WPF Container/grid layout

Tags: wpf, layout, grid, containers

I need to create a WPF container that can display a collection of 3 different controls types. Each control's height and width is based off the others.  Ex, if controlA is 200X200, controlB will be 100X200 and controlC will be 50X50.  I need to find out how I can reate a container smart enough to arrange these controls by finding the best layout based on available space and the quantity of each control type.

Take the case below where we have 1 instance of controlA, 1 instance of controlB and 2 instances of controlC.  Notice how this elegantly positioned giving it a compact look as opposed to a list of sequential controls.

[container http://onlinegolfpool.com/images/grid.png](http://onlinegolfpool.com/images/grid.png)

Any ideas on how to tackle?  Should I use a grid and calculate this on my own?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have an example in comments below of "5 instances of controlA, 3 instances of controlB and 11 controlC". In this sort of situation, are the ratios the same? Meaning any A will still be twice the height of B, and any B will be twice the Width of C?

Comment: Yes, the ratio (size) for the types/controls are always the same - the number of types/controls is the only thing that differs.

Comment: It sounds like you either need to create your own custom `Panel`, or determine if you can perform some algorithm on the data to determine the number of rows/columns you'll need and the Row/Column for each item, and use an `ItemsControl` with the `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to a `Grid`

Comment: And to clarify, will your controls actually have a fixed size, or just a fixed ratio? For example, will ItemC always be 100x50? Also, is your available area a fixed size? Meaning, does it have a maximum height or width?

Comment: Thanks for your update, to you answer your question -- nothing will be or should be fixed sized.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should use Grid, but don't even think of calculating this on your own :) 
Use asterisk(*) to define relative sizes for each cell. WPF will do the rest for you.

Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Pink" Stroke="Black" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Asterisk is very powerful, and many people don't even know about it :) Enjoy!

Comment: Yeah but what happens when I have 5 instances of controlA, 3 instances of controlB and 11 controlC?  I need something flexible and smart enough to handle these situations as well.

Comment: Then you could use UniformGrid, nested in a cell

Comment: Is it possible to see a .xaml example, one in which I am binding to a list of colors, where I can set ItemSource{Binding Path=MyColorsCollection}?

Comment: Don't think so. You have to create your own `Panel` which can arrange the elements however you want. Then use it in `ItemsControl` with your `ItemSource{Binding Path=MyColorsCollection}`.

Comment: Useful link how to create custom `Panel`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a stackpanel instead of gridpanel. Then give hardcoded width to any control you want and rest of the area will adjust itself.

```
<StackPanel Orientation=Horizontal>
    <leftcontrol/>
    <StackPanel Orientation=Vertical>
        <firstcontrol/>
        <StackPanel Orientation=Horizontal>
            <bottomLeftControl/>
            <bottomRightControl/>
        </StackPanel> 
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Yeah but what happens when I have 5 instances of controlA, 3 instances of controlB and 11 controlC?  I need something flexible and smart enough to handle these situations as well.

Comment: Use DockPanel and let it handle the layout

Comment: Vishal, can you provide me with a .xaml example, one in which I am binding to a list of colors, where I can set ItemSource{Binding Path=MyColorsCollection}?